# How to execute already declared functions using setTimeout() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

Basically, if I want to execute a function in `setTimeout()`, I'd have to declare it inside `setTimeout()`, like something similar to this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    safe.isBroken = false;
    safe.amount = randNumberBetween(500, 1500);
}, 30000);
```

But I can't do something like this:

```
setTimeout(safeRefill(30000)
```

Any way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, like this:

```
setTimeout(safeRefill, time)
```

But, in order to parse arguments to safeRefill, you'd have to do it like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){ safeRefill(arg1, arg2) }, time)
```

Comment: Thanks. I had really low rep at the time so I couldn't comment nor mark as answered or upvote.

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can certainly use your already declared functions within `setTimeout`. 
All you need to do is call your existing functions inside the anonymous function that is passed as a first parameter to  `setTimeout` function.

Here is the fiddle demonstrating the same. [http://jsfiddle.net/0449f1dn/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/0449f1dn/)

Hope it helps!